# Revert Local GitHub Repo All The Way Back

Tags: git, git-reset, git-revert

I know you can go in order of reverting commits but is there a way to completely revert a repo to when it was first initialized?

This sounds extreme but I messed up with my commits because I was trying to use an existing React project to replace an existing git repo (to replace the contents in there), and fetched when I shouldn’t have. The remote was off and now the original files from the React project are gone.

There’s too many commits (done because I had to keep the branches in sync to revert since I kept getting errors). I’m sorry this is silly, but losing all this is would be disastrous. I rather just start over from before I turned that directory into a git repo (which was today).

Comment: when it was first initialized, it was empty. do you mean reverting back to first commit?

Comment: @eis Yes. Though in my case, it was an existing React project when I first initialized as a git repo so it wasn’t empty.

Comment: initialized repo is always empty. Maybe you mean when you cloned/forked it, not when initializing it?

Comment: If I used ‘git init’ on an already present and non-empty React directory, is that still an empty git repo? I’m talking locally. Even in the remote, there was files from the old project (not React).  I wanted to replace the old git repo with this new React one.

Comment: Yes. "git init" will create an empty repo. First commit actually adds some files there.

Answer (score 2):

The first commit's SHA can be obtained with `git rev-list`:

```sh
> git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD
<SHA>
```

Using that SHA, you can `git reset`:

```sh
> git reset --hard <SHA>
```

Note: This is a destructive command, so back up your folder for extra safety.

Comment: Just to make sure I don’t mess it up again, this will restore local files I had after ‘git init’? Or changes will only affect the remote repo?

Comment: It will revert local files bringing your repo back to how it was right after the first commit

Comment: "after the first commit" bit is crucial. if the files were not in the first commit, they won't be there. @LaLaLottie

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove your repository with all your commits, delete directory `.git` in your project directory, and then start again with initializing git repository `git init .`

Answer (score 1):

Try performing the following command

```
git reset --hard <commit_sha>
```

e.g.

```
git reset --hard a012809fa
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I misunderstood at first—I thought you wanted to keep the *current work-tree copy* of each file.  If you want the copy that was in the first commit, use `git log` to find the first commit, then use `git reset --hard` with the hash ID from that commit, as in [joshnuss's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61607575/1256452) or [tuvok's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61607567/1256452).  (Since joshnuss's answer shows how to find the hash ID, that's the one to use, to do this.)

It's then up to you whether to remove and re-create the underlying Git repository in the `.git` directory, or keep the current one: your branch name `master` will now identify that very first commit, rather than the last commit, and `git log` will only show you the one commit.

---

To expand on [Vadik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61607557/1256452) and show you why it may be the right one for what you want to do, keep these things in mind about Git:

- Git is really all about *commits*.  Git has branch names, and other names, but their main function is to help you—and Git itself—find commits.
- A commit is a full snapshot of all of your files.  These files, once inside the commit like this, can *never be changed*.  They are in a special, read-only, Git-only format that only Git can use.
- A *repository* is fancier than "just two databases", but at its heart, it's a big database that holds all of your *commits* (along with other supporting Git objects), plus a smaller database of the names—the branch and tag names and so on.
- When you `git clone`, `git fetch`, or `git push`, you're connecting your Git to some other Git.  The two Gits talk to each other and transfer commits around.  For the most part, while they may *look* at each others names (branch and tag names) they don't necessarily transfer the *names*—it's the *commits* that matter. Whichever Git is *receiving* commits will update some name, once the receive is done, so as to remember the commits.  But it's the *commits* that they're really copying around.  Commits get shared around; names don't, or at least not necessarily.

Since the files inside a Git commit literally *can't* be modified, and can't really be used by anything other than Git itself, they're all just *archives*.  Git *has to* give you a way to extract any given commit, so that you can get ordinary everyday files that you can *use*.

These ordinary everyday files go in what Git calls your *working tree* or *work-tree*.  The work-tree is, in a very real sense, not part of the repository at all.  It's not a commit, and it's not a branch name: it's not in Git's two primary databases.  (In fact, you can run a storage-only Git that has no work-tree at all: this is how servers like GitHub operate.)

But the work-tree has all the files *you* work with.  If your goal is to erase everything you did so far *in* Git, perhaps irrecoverably, and start over—but keep the files *you* are working with—then what you need is to get yourself rid of the existing *repository* while keeping your work-tree.

Fortunately, this is *very easy*, because the work-tree is where you work, and the repository proper is in a hidden directory / folder at the top of your work-tree named `.git`.  Move this `.git` out of the way, or delete it, and the *repository* is elsewhere, or completely gone.  Then run `git init` with no additional options or arguments (or `git init .` but the `.` is redundant) and Git will create a new totally-empty repository by creating a new `.git` folder / directory, and putting into it the supporting files, including empty name and objects databases.

(If you *move* the `.git` directory out of the way—into some other project folder for instance—that gives you the ability to go into it later and find commits again, in case you decide starting over was a bad idea after all.)

Comment: I really appreciate this very detailed answer.  This will help me understand the git actions I take from now on.  But what I'm worried about is this solution gets rid of the current repo, but not restore the local directory, is that correct?  So if I remove the `.git` then what I have in that local directory is what I will have, right? It won't be the old files?  So should I follow what the others said and reset it first?

Comment: You *can* do a `git reset --hard`, if you want to wipe out the *current* files and replace them with *earlier* files.  Or, for a very similar effect, you *can* do a `git checkout` of an older commit. Either way you're telling Git: *replace what I have now, in my work-tree, with the frozen files from an earlier commit*. The question you need to answer for yourself is: which files do you *want* to have?

Comment: I want to have the files I had before I did `git init`.

Comment: OK, in that case, you do want to reset-to or check-out your initial commit, i.e., put into your work-tree those files that you put into your initial commit. (Presumably you ran `git init`, then `git add .`, then `git commit`, originally, so that you committed the files you had before the `git init` step.)